# Magical Import using two mappedKeyName for relationship

Tags: magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.1

I have Team model and Player model

So When I create Player I have response that return me this:

```
"palyer":
{
teamID = 10
...
```

I have the next setting in xcdatamodel for Player.team relationship

mappedKeyName - player.teamID

mappedKeyName.1 - teamID

relatedByAttribute - teamID

mappedKeyName.1 I am using because when I request player list api it return me

```
{
teamID = 10,
...
},
{
teamID = 11,
}
...
```

so then I am using MR_importFromArray for Player entities.

but seems magical import won't work in the second case. I have checked response and it return me teamID for each request.

I have noticed that it works only with one mappedKeyName

Or maybe I confused about goals of mapped keys?

Answer (score 2):

This was a [bug in MagicalRecord 2.2 and earlier](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/pull/723). It is [fixed in the upcoming 2.3](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/commit/7e4c076f697a151bcf39dd34b7e9870da661ac79) release.